# Calling express routes via AJAX to redirect the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

In an express app , i have an **ajax post** call in the index.ejs which has its url pointing to a "**/featureDet**" route (declared with app.use('**/featureDet', featureDet);** in the app.js

this is the **index.ejs** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="/javascripts/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>

    modernizr :
    <h1><%= typeof modernizr!='undefined' ? modernizr : '' %></h1>     

    <script>

    console.log( "the Modernizr object is  : " + JSON.stringify(Modernizr));

        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log( "document loaded" );

            //console.log( "the Modernizr object is  : " + JSON.stringify(Modernizr) );
            
            $.post( "/featureDet", { "modernizr": JSON.stringify(Modernizr)}, function() {
              console.log( "success in sending POST req" );
            })
              .done(function() {
                console.log( "POST req reaches the server" );
                //window.location = "/featureDet";
              })
              .fail(function() {
                console.log( "error" );
              })
              .always(function() {
                console.log( "finished" );
            });

        });
     
        $(window).load(function() {
            console.log( "window loaded" );
        });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the **featureDet.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var title, modernizr;

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log('a POST req was sent to the featureDet route!!'); 
  //console.log('The POST req modernizr parameter :: ' + req.body.modernizr);   
  
  
  
  modernizr = JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr);  
  console.log('modernizr : ' + modernizr);

  // trying a render() with passing params
  //res.render('featureDet', { title: 'Feature Detection 2', modernizr: JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr) });
  
  // trying a send() with passing params
  //res.send({ title: 'Feature Detection 2', modernizr: JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr) });

  // trying a json response method1 (with send()):
  //res.type('json');
  //res.send({ modernizr: modernizr });

  // trying a json response method2 (with .json()):
  //res.json({ title: 'Feature Detection 2', modernizr: JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr) })


  // trying a redirect:
  //res.end();
   //res.redirect('/featureDet');

  //trying a redirect with passing params in req.session:
  /*req.session.modernizr = JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr);
  req.session.title = 'Feature Detection 2';
  res.redirect('/featureDet');*/
  
  //trying a redirect with params set in the url
  //res.redirect('/featureDet'
                //+'?title=' + encodeURIComponent('Feature Detection 2')
                //+ '&modernizr=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(req.body.modernizr))
               //);
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('a GET req was sent to the featureDet route!!');    
  console.log('modernizr : ' + modernizr);
  res.render('featureDet', { title: 'Feature Detection 2', modernizr: modernizr });
  
});
module.exports = router;
```

and finally, this is the **featureDet.ejs**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Feature Detection 2 </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    
  </head>
  <body>
  This is featureDet.ejs
  <br/><br/>
  <h1><%= typeof modernizr!='undefined' ? modernizr : '' %></h1> 
  </body>
</html>
```

So as shown in the comments in the **featureDet.js**, i have been trying all ways to make the browser change the displayed view from index.ejs to featureDet.ejs or to get a json from it (see the json methods i used) but i just always get these results only as Responses in the firebug console showing the sent request status as shown in here :

When htlm response :

[image]

When json response:

[image]

After reading many answers the only solution to redirect the page was to use

> window.location = "/featureDet";

in the .done() of the POST call. I wonder why all what i was trying failed as the route itself is triggered (so the code is reached..) but the response never affect the page in the browser. Is it impossible to make a redirect after an ajax call (i also tried a GET ajax call to an express router but it didn't work too). Please, i need an explanation in case it's impossible.

Comment: "Is it impossible to make a redirect after an ajax call" - redirected response has no meaning for ajax request, since the purpose of the ajax request is not to reload the page.

Comment: thanks but i just was wondering that the route code itself is executed without any effect and that's strange for me that an ajax call would have a different effect on the app behaviour..

Comment: i know that ajax doesn't reload the page but i didn't know that it would not let it being reloaded or redirected by another way.